# Query using min() not showing the correct result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Vars` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `userID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `viewedT` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

I have these values:

```
INSERT INTO `Vars` (`ID`, `code`, `userID`, `viewedT`) VALUES
(1, 'alex1234567', 1, 25),
(2, 'Dan1234567', 2, 15);
```

Now the weird thing is that I can not get the correct results with this query:

```
select min(`viewedT`), `code` From Vars
```

The result is:

```
 min(`viewedT`)     Code
 15                 alex1234567
```

**EDIT:** What I need is to select the `code` which have `min(viewsT)`

I'm sure that I'm missing something really small in the syntax which will bring me downvotes, but I need to know my mistake and learn from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to find the one row with the minimum value, use

```
select viewedT, code, id from vars
  where viewedT= (select min(viewedT) from vars)
```

If more than one row contains the minimum value you will get all such rows. I.e. if two rows had the value 15 for `viewedT`, you would get both.

Answer (score 2):

```
select viewedT,Code from Vars 
where viewedT=(select MIN(V.viewedT) from Vars as V)
```

It will give you following result

```
viewedT         Code

15          Dan1234567
```